# QuickReport - How to print multiple copies?

Tags: delphi, quickreports

How to print multiple copies of report?

The following code only prints 1 copy:

```
fmRpt.QuickRep1.PrinterSettings.Copies := 2;
fmRpt.QuickRep1.Print;
```

Comment: What have you done to diagnose the problem?

Comment: We've been using QuickReport in our software for many years, using many different versions, and have never had this problem. But, you have the full QR source code of whichever version you're using, so I suggest take the debugger in there and see what happens. Which Delphi version? Which QuickReport version?